# How can I remove the default digraphs?

Tags: digraphs

I like Vim’s [digraph feature](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html) but I find the number of default digraphs overwhelming. Is there a way to clear all of these so that the only digraph definitions are the ones that I created myself (e.g. in my vimrc)?

Comment: Not really. But you can use e.g. my plugin [unicode](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) which offers the better `:Digraphs` command.

Comment: FWIW, I've posted a request to the vim dev group to gauge whether this is worth putting in to the product. I've already tested a local change to 8.1.412 as a proof of concept and it seems to work okay. No help for you *right* now of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be able to unset a digraph with the `digraph_set()` function, passing the empty string as its second argument, like this:

`:call digraph_set("gx", "")`

But that only seems to work on user-defined digraphs, and not on Vim's default digraphs.  And you asked about removing the default digraphs.

(Note that if I redefine a default digraph, and then redefine it again to an empty string, it seems to revert back to Vim's default definition.)

---

If all you want to do is see the digraphs that you define, you can see them with this command:

`:echo digraph_getlist()`

You'll see only your user-defined digraphs.  (As opposed to the `:digraphs` command, which shows them all.)

---

But if your goal is to remove the default digraphs entirely so that you don't accidentally enter them as you're typing as normal, then you need a different approach.

If that's the case, I found a work-around that might work for you.  Try this command and see if it works for you:

`:for d in digraph_getlist(1) | call digraph_set(d[0], d[0][1]) | endfor`

What this does is take every character-pair (both default and user-defined) and redefine it to be its second character, effectively nullifying the digraph.

For example, if you enter the character pair `i:`, instead of replacing it with `ï`, it will be replaced with `:`, essentially making the digraph a no-op.

Whichever digraphs you define after that will be the ones that have a real effect.